# Converting a string to a list and seperate each element

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I have a use case in which I enter indexes and descriptions which belong to a round. I created a JS function that allows me to enter these indexes and descriptions. When I strip the data from the post request I get the following data:

```
['0,This is a testround', '1,This is a new testround']
```

I want to split this data so that I can seperate the 0 in an index variable and the following description "This is a testround" in a description variable. Please note that the description can only contain comma's. The indexes are not always corresponding with the indexes of an array: [[0,"Description1"],[5,"Description2"]] could happen

A possible solution could be to split the string on a comma and use str[0] for the index and the other parts for the description but to me this would look like an ugly solution.

What should I do?

I use the following JS to save the rounds to a playerdata div from which i extract the list above (in which items is the list with the index and description)

```
  function item_checkbox(items,n) {
return `
  <input type="checkbox" style="display:none;" name="${itemList[n]}" value="${items}" checked>
`
  }

  function add_to_itemData(items, n) {
    itemDataEl = document.getElementById(itemData[n])
    itemDataEl.innerHTML = itemDataEl.innerHTML + item_checkbox(items, n)
  }
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You could always just regex replace `^\d+,` with nothing and get rid of the numbers.  Since your strings are already in an array, their index are already provided.

Comment: Or do a map and slice off the string after the index of the first comma.

Comment: Hi @Taplar I should have made it more clear but the indexes are not always corresponding with the arr index. e.g i can enter two rounds: [[0,"Description1"],[5,"Description2"]]. I have edited the question

Comment: Egh, alright, so that makes things less straight forward, :)

Comment: you can use ```map()``` and use the indexes as keys and description as value

Comment: `data = ['0,This is a testround', '1,This is a new testround']` and later `new_data = [ item.split(",") for item in data]`

Comment: maybe in JS you should generate data `[[0,'This is a testround'], [1,'This is a new testround']]` and sent it in JSON format - and then you can use module `json` to easily convert it from JSON format to Python list.

Answer (score 0):

While you say that it would be an "ugly" solution to solve it by splitting, I think it's a pretty straightforward routine, given the format the data is returned to you.

```js
['0,This is a testround', '1,This is a new testround'].map(v => v.split(','));
```

... would translate correctly to:

```js
[
    [ "0", "This is a testround" ],
    [ "1", "This is a new testround" ]
]
```

But I guess I get what you mean. There are a few possible problems - for example, that of key uniqueness. You could solve this one by keeping each row into Javascript objects instead of arrays, and you can convert it quite  easily by using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), since it conveniently accepts each row of bidimensional arrays as key/value pairs:

```
Object.fromEntries([
    [ "0", "This is a testround" ],
    [ "1", "This is a new testround" ],
    [ "1", "This is a dupe testround" ] // this will overwrite the previous entry
]);

// {0: "This is a testround", 1: "This is a dupe testround"}
```

You might want to take a few extra steps for additional control, like using `.trim()` to remove leading or trailing whitespaces or testing/filtering/splitting them using a custom regex.